# Fatal error Uncaught SoapFault exception SOAP ERROR Parsing WSDL could not load from

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to connect through SOAP client. the code works well in windows, I am getting a response immediately.  when I moved the  code to CentOS or Ubuntu  I am getting the error in the following line

`$client = new SoapClient($soapwsUrl);`

I  tried in `PHP 5.x` and `PHP 7.x`  still the problem is same.

the following are enabled

```
php.ini file

extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
```

Comment: is the WSDL under a `https://` link? if so, can you `file_get_contents()` it without failure?

Comment: I'm going to guess certificate error.